# Matlab how to cover or cylinder

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

On the Matlab website, code that creates a cylinder with both ends covered up [is given](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/plot-cylinder.html):

```
plot(plot::Cylinder(1, [-3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]);
```

but this is for Matlab R2013a.

This code doesn't work in Matlab R2008a, because it doesn't accept '::'. How can I create such a plot?

Answer (score 2):

`plot::cylinder` is a function from `MuPad`. This is like maple code. When matlab generate his cylinder is like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cylinder.html). For MuPad information go [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-mupad-notebooks-and-program-files.html)

**EDIT**

To be able to create cylinder with base.

Type in Matlab command window :

`mupad`

That will open the MuPad Interface. After you just need to execute your cylinder command :

`plot(plot::Cylinder(1,[-3,0,0],[3,0,0]));`

Comment: Thanks, but i want to covered up and covered down the cylinder??

Comment: If you want it, you will need to look at MuPad code. That will explain how to use this kind of code. So in matlab type `mupad` and after type `plot(plot::Cylinder(1, [-3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]));`